# SSRS 2008: Execute dataset on boolean value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Currently using a Boolean parameter and some custom code to check at least one of the user accessible parameters has data. If this Boolean is true I need to run a stored procedure on my one dataset otherwise I want it to do nothing as I have a textbox for an error with visibility set to the Boolean's value.

[image: Boolean Parameter with Default Value]

[image: Custom code]

```
=Code.NoParameters(Parameters!StartDate.Value,Parameters!EndDate.Value,Parameters!ClientCode.Value(0))

Function NoParameters(StartDate as DateTime, EndDate as DateTime, ClientCode as String) As Boolean
Dim RetValue as Boolean
RetValue = "False"
If(StartDate = Nothing And EndDate = Nothing And ClientCode = Nothing)
RetValue = "True"
Else
RetValue = "False"
End If
Return RetValue
End Function
```

I've tried a few variations of

```
If IsEmpty = False EXEC sp_grand_smslog_processing
```

and also

```
iif (Parameters!IsEmpty.Value = False, "sp_grand_smslog_processing" , " ")
```

This is the last thing I need to be able to publish this report which I've been working on for a whole week. Please Halp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that SSRS expects a dataset to always have the same data structure returned, if you do not execute the query then nothing is returned when what you actually need is an empty dataset.

2 basic ways of doing this.

First you could modify the stored proc, (you may have to pass it an additional parameter which prevents execution) and then just return no results.

However, I would probably avoid that as it means that your stored proc has to be modified and you might not want to do that, and it also means you still end up running the stored proc.

I would change my dataset query to be something along these lines...

```
DECLARE @SpResults TABLE(myCol1 int, myCol2 int etc....) -- <<-- This should match the output form your stored proc exactly.

IF @RunThis = 1 -- execute the SP and dump results into @SpResults table
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @SpResults
          EXEC myStoredProc
    END
-- finally return the table contents
-- The @RunTHis = 0 then the table will be empty, but still valid
SELECT * FROM @SpResults
```

**Note:** You could swap out the table variable for a temp table depending on the size of the results etc, but the principle is exactly the same.

Comment: Alan thank you so much for trying to help out again. I tried the solution you presented but I am getting a query execution error whenever the statement actually runs the SP.

Comment: So I had assumed that SSRS would continue to send my parameters even if I was applying an EXEC I was so wrong.

Comment: You'll need to include the parameters in the dataset query. In my exmaple only `@RunThis` (replace this with the name of you boolean parameter) would be passed. If you add the parameter names to the `EXEC myStoedProc` line then they will be passed but they were not shown in your exmaple so I didn't include those in the answer.

Comment: Yes my mistake Alan. I can't thank you enough you have helped me more than I you know! Where can I send you a cup of coffee or a beer?

Comment: One more question still related to this. Could I do a check for not just @RunThis = 1 but for another variable as well so that both pass?

Comment: Yes. If you include a parameter name that matches the name of your SSRS report parameter but you DON'T declare it in your dataset query, then it will be passed to the dataset query. Then just change the `IF` statement to some thing like `IF @RunThis =1 AND @myOtherParameter ='x'` etc...

Comment: So I lied. I have one more issue that I think might be related to switching from running the report with a query instead of just calling the SP directly. Now when I input multiple values for some of those fields the report outright bombs. New question for this?

Comment: Good ol `=Join(Parameters!TerritoryMulti.Value, ",")` fixed it. Alan I am fairly new to stackoverflow but if there is a way to tip you for all your help please let me know! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I answer on SO as I like helping people. I only ask that good answered as marked as accepted as it helps people looking for similar answers in the future. I have learnt a lot from SO over the years so it's only fair to give something back.